# Coursera: Calculating sum of numbers in the fibonacci sequence between two specific points in the series

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, fibonacci-sequence

## Question

This is an assignment for a Coursera course.

[image]

This is the algorithm I wrote.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FibonacciPartialSum {
    private static long getFibonacciPartialSumNaive(long from, long to) {
        if (to <= 1)
            return to;

        long prev = 0;
        long cur = 1;
        long sum;

        if(from == 1) {
            sum = 1;
        }
        else {
            sum = 0;
        }

        for (long i = 2; i <= to; i++) {
            long temp_prev = prev;
            prev = cur;
            cur = (cur + temp_prev) % 10;

            if (i >= from) {
                sum = (sum + cur) % 10;
            }

        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        long from = scanner.nextLong();
        long to = scanner.nextLong();
        //long from = 1234;
        //long to = 12345;
        System.out.println(getFibonacciPartialSumNaive(from, to));
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

When I submit it to auto grader in Coursera it states that I failed the time test.

> ```
> Failed case #8/12: time limit exceeded Input: 1 10000000000
>
> Your output:
>
> stderr:
>
> (Time used: 3.03/1.50, memory used: 26427392/536870912.)
> ```

Comment: `This is an assignment` - and a trivial one: what do you know/can you find out about *F₁+…+Fₙ*?

Comment: @greybeard This is one of 8 questions for a weekly assignment. I figured out that to get the correct final answer you don't have to add the total numbers. Just adding the last digit (hence use %10) is enough. I didn't figure out anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Runtime improvement

If you take a look at the last digit of the first few fibonacci numbers you will see that the digits are repeated after 60 numbers. As the digits in this range have a sum of `0` you can calculate the sum for `[from%60,to%60]` instead.

#### Bug

The task states that the given integer are non-negative, `0` is a valid value. Currently you are returning i.e. `1` for the range `[0,2]` as `0` is treated as `2`, the initialization of sum has to be changed to:

```
if (from <= 1) {
    sum = 1;
} else {
    sum = 0;
}
```

(I would initialize `sum` with a ternary operator `long sum = from <= 1 ? 1 : 0` instead.)

#### Types

As the values of `sum`, `prev` and `cur` are always in the range `[0,10)`, you can use `int` instead of `long` for these variables, `int` arithmetic is likely to be faster than `long` arithmetic.

#### Alternative implementation

The remaining range is quite small -> you could cache the results for every number in the range `[0,60)` to avoid calculating the sum on each invocation.

```
private static final byte[] DIGIT_SUM = {
        0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 2, 0, 3, 4, 8,
        3, 2, 6, 9, 6, 6, 3, 0, 4, 5,
        0, 6, 7, 4, 2, 7, 0, 8, 9, 8,
        8, 7, 6, 4, 1, 6, 8, 5, 4, 0,
        5, 6, 2, 9, 2, 2, 5, 8, 4, 3,
        8, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 8, 0, 9, 0};

private static int fibonacciPartialSum(long m, long n) {
    assert m <= n & (m | n) >= 0;
    int v = fibSumLastDigit(n);
    return m == 0 ? v : (v -= fibSumLastDigit(m - 1)) + (10 & v >> -1);
}

private static int fibSumLastDigit(long n) {
    return DIGIT_SUM[(int) (n % 60)];
}
```

Comment: `look at [the] first few Fibonacci numbers [: last] digits are repeated after 60 numbers.` MMD

Answer (score 2):

The most interesting optimisation I can think of is making use of the [pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period).

This says that the sum of the first N fib numbers mod 10 is cyclic with period 60.

This means that the SumF(1) = sumF(61) = sumF(121) ...

So if we add the following lines to the start of the method:

```
from = from%60;
to = to%60;
```

we get a really great improvement ... but also introduced an error. This will only work if the new `to` is still larger than the new `from`.

This can easily be fixed though:

```
if(to < from){
    to += 60;
}
```

The rest of your method can remain the same.